# Symfony Check if at least one of two fields isn't empty on form validation of CollectionType

Tags: forms, constraints, symfony4

In a previous question ([Symfony Check if at least one of two fields isn't empty on form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60720662/symfony-check-if-at-least-one-of-two-fields-isnt-empty-on-form-validation)) I had asked help for form validation using Callback. The answer given by @hous was right, but it doesn't work for elements in a CollectionType, reason why I'm opening a new question.

Based on the previous answer I have done the following:

Here is my "mother" Form:

```php
class BookingVisitorType extends AbstractType
{
    private $router;
    private $translator;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('visitors', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => VisitorType::class,
                'label' => 'entity.booking.visitors',
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                    'delete-url' => $options['visitor-delete-url']
                ],
                'constraints' =>[
                    new Count([
                        'min' => 1,
                        'minMessage' => 'validator.visitor.at-least-one-visitor',
                        'max' => $options['numberOfPlaces'],
                        'maxMessage' => 'validator.visitor.cannot-have-more-visitor-than-spaces',
                        'exactMessage' => 'validator.visitor.exact-message'
                    ])
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Booking::class,
            'numberOfPlaces' => 1,
            'visitor-delete-url' => ''
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here is my "son" Form:

```php
class VisitorType extends AbstractType
{
    private $phone;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'entity.visitor.first-name',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 2,
                        'max' => 255
                    ]),
                    new Regex([
                        'pattern' => "/[\pL\s\-]*/",
                        'message' => 'validator.visitor.not-valide-first-name'
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->add('phone', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'entity.visitor.phone-number',
                'required' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new Regex([
                        'pattern' => "/[0-9\s\.\+]*/",
                        'message' => 'validator.visitor.not-valide-phone-number'
                    ]),
                    new Callback(function($phone, ExecutionContextInterface $context){
                        $this->phone = $phone;
                    }),
                ]
            ])
            ->add('email', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'entity.visitor.email',
                'required' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new Email(),
                    new Callback(function($email, ExecutionContextInterface $context){
                        if ($this->phone == null && $email == null) {
                            $context->buildViolation('validator.visitor.email-or-phone-required')->addViolation();
                        }
                    }),
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Visitor::class,
            'error_bubbling' => false,
            'delete-url' => '',
        ]);
    }
}
```

My "booking" (shortened) class:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BookingRepository")
 */
class Booking
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Visitor", mappedBy="booking", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $visitors;
}
```

And finally my "visitor" (shortened) class:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\VisitorRepository")
 */
class Visitor
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Booking", inversedBy="visitors")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $booking;

    /**
    * @Assert\Callback
    */
    public function validateAtLeastEmailOrPhone(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
    {
        if ($this->getPhone() === null && $this->getEmail() === null) {
            $context->buildViolation('validator.visitor.email-or-phone-required-for-all')->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

I've been able to workaround the problem by adding a property to my VisitorType form that I define with the Callback constraint on the phone value and then check it with a Callback constraint on the email field, but it doesn't seem very "good practice".

If I only try to call the Callback constraint I get the following error message: "Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given"

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an callback function you could create your own [Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html). Then the Check would be reusable.

I've been using this to check the password on registration against custom rules.